# Using css inside JS code to resize a div

Tags: javascript, css

I don't really master css and JS codes as well.
And i have to do something like this:

Transforming this code in css:

```
<div class="siebui-span-lg-6 siebui-span-md-6 siebui-span-sm-12" style="width:60%"></div>
```

To a JS code.

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: No code here, was it an accident?

Answer (score 0):

You can access element style through `element.style` field, and then set it to some value:

```js
var divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div.siebui-span-lg-6.siebui-span-md-6.siebui-span-sm-12')[0];
divElement.style.width = "60%";
console.log(divElement.style.width);
```

```html
<div class="siebui-span-lg-6 siebui-span-md-6 siebui-span-sm-12"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName('siebui-span-lg-6 siebui-span-md-6 siebui-span-sm-12');
for (var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].style.width="60%";
}
</script>
```

Or you can add id to div and just:

```
document.getElementsById('yourId').style.width="60%";
```

Answer (score 0):

I did all your suggestions but it didn't return the wanted result :/
The div doesn't move from his default width '50%'